# Why does my mvc project redirect to default 403 error page instead of the one I have redirected it to, on IIS not on local?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, http-status-code-403

I have set up an error page to be redirected to if 403 error is thrown and it works on local environment but not when deployed to IIS where it redirects to default 403 forbidden page i.e. 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Why?

Code:

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
  <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
```

C#:

CustomAuthorize:

```
 public class CustomeAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // just to ensure if the unauthorized request is from an authenticated user or a visitor.

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)   // just a visitor since he/she doesn't need any login to proceed
            {
                //filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/AuthorizeFailedError.cshtml" };  
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Errors", action = "AuthorizeFailedError" }));
            }
            else //authenticated user but authorized to the requested page
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml" };  
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm new to this and see that my answer wasn't that well shown I'll try again.

I see your customErrors in your web.config doesn't have any redirects in it as IIS will use this try adding something like this

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error403Page" statusCode="403" />
</customErrors>
```

or if you have a default error page you want to go to you can do something like this

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error403Page" statusCode="403" />
</customErrors>
```

more information can be found here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx